# What run mode should be used for ServiceBus triggered WebJob?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azureservicebus

I have a WebJob that has is meant to be triggered whenever a ServiceBus queue item shows up

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("%ServiceBusHighPriorityQueueName%")] BrokeredMessage message)
```

Some sites state the following

- Continuous: A WebJob that will be always running
- Triggered: A WebJob that is run on-demand when an API call is made or on when a scheduled condition is reached.

I assume ServiceBus queue trigger handler is "Triggered" instead of "Continuous", so what should be used when setting the **webjob-publish-settings.json** parameter **runMode**?

Since it is triggered, does the AppService still need to be AlwaysOn?

Comment: You need to set the job as continuous and have always on. The jobhost use an async pump to get message so the job need to run all the time.

Answer (score 5):

When using the WebJobs SDK with a host that blocks, the WebJobs needs to be set as continuous, even though from the point of view of individual functions, they behave as if they are triggered.

Basically, continuous is correct whenever you have an exe that runs forever, and that is the case here.

And of course, do do need to have Always On enabled.